# change the ajax progressbar of dotnetnukes

Tags: dotnetnuke, progress-bar

Is there a way to change the default ajax progressbar that is there in dotnetnukes.

Its not for changing the image but i would like to use an altogether different progressbar. The current one displays the progressbar at the bottom of the section. The requirement to replace it with one covering the entire section or part of it. The section has a search criteria on top and the results below. The progressbar needs to appear above the criteria so that the user will not change it while the search is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the animated image you can replace with your own if you have one.

Comment: The progress bar is dynamically injected to the bottom of a container where a control is using it. You can somehow target it using the control id and use YourControlID_Prog to manipulate the positioning. Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @DangIT, you can find the gif with name progressbar.gif in images folder in the root of dnn installation. just delete it, and place another image with the same name will do the trick for you

Comment: check this - http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/disable_updatepanel_contents_d.html